# Rotate a vector about another vector

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, rotation

I am writing a 3d vector class for OpenGL.  How do I rotate a vector v1 about another vector v2 by an angle A?

Comment: What do you mean by rotating "along" a vector?

Comment: i mean "against" or "around",sorry for my weak english.

Comment: I would recommend reading introductionary book to 3d math instead of asking such questions here every time you find a problem. One very good introduction to subject is http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Graphics-Development-Wordware-Library/dp/1556229119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest-to-understand way would be rotating the coordinate axis so that vector v2 aligns with the Z axis, then rotate by A around the Z axis, and rotate back so that the Z axis aligns with v2.

When you have written down the rotation matrices for the three operations, you'll probably notice that you apply three matrices after each other. To reach the same effect, you can multiply the three matrices.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but this is overly complex.  A simpler solution, which I would argue is actually easier to understand (but that's just me) is to use the quaternion based approach Brett Hale suggests.

Comment: @andand: Quaternions are nice and simple, sure, once you have understood quaternions. The OP seems to have had difficulties with normal 3D linear algebra, quaternions are probably three steps too high on the ladder for now.

Answer (score 6):

You may find [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) to be a more elegant and efficient solution.

---

After seeing this answer bumped recently, I though I'd provide a more robust answer. One that can be used without necessarily understanding the full mathematical implications of quaternions. I'm going to assume (given the C++ tag) that you have something like a `Vector3` class with 'obvious' functions like `inner`, `cross`, and `*=` scalar operators, etc...

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>

...

void make_quat (float quat[4], const Vector3 & v2, float angle)
{
    // BTW: there's no reason you can't use 'doubles' for angle, etc.
    // there's not much point in applying a rotation outside of [-PI, +PI];
    // as that covers the practical 2.PI range.

    // any time graphics / floating point overlap, we have to think hard
    // about degenerate cases that can arise quite naturally (think of
    // pathological cancellation errors that are *possible* in seemingly
    // benign operations like inner products - and other running sums).

    Vector3 axis (v2);

    float rl = sqrt(inner(axis, axis));
    if (rl < FLT_EPSILON) // we'll handle this as no rotation:
    {
        quat[0] = 0.0, quat[1] = 0.0, quat[2] = 0.0, quat[3] = 1.0;
        return; // the 'identity' unit quaternion.
    }

    float ca = cos(angle);

    // we know a maths library is never going to yield a value outside
    // of [-1.0, +1.0] right? Well, maybe we're using something else -
    // like an approximating polynomial, or a faster hack that's a little
    // rough 'around the edge' cases? let's *ensure* a clamped range:
    ca = (ca < -1.0f) ? -1.0f : ((ca > +1.0f) ? +1.0f : ca);

    // now we find cos / sin of a half-angle. we can use a faster identity
    // for this, secure in the knowledge that 'sqrt' will be valid....

    float cq = sqrt((1.0f + ca) / 2.0f); // cos(acos(ca) / 2.0);
    float sq = sqrt((1.0f - ca) / 2.0f); // sin(acos(ca) / 2.0);

    axis *= sq / rl; // i.e., scaling each element, and finally:

    quat[0] = axis[0], quat[1] = axis[1], quat[2] = axis[2], quat[3] = cq;
}
```

Thus `float quat[4]` holds a unit quaternion that represents the axis and angle of rotation, given the original arguments `(, v2, A)`.

Here's a routine for quaternion multiplication. SSE/SIMD can probably speed this up, but complicated transform & lighting are typically GPU-driven in most scenarios. If you remember *complex* number multiplication as a little weird, *quaternion* multiplication is more so. Complex number multiplication is a commutative operation: `a*b = b*a`. Quaternions don't even preserve this property, i.e., `q*p != p*q` :

```
static inline void
qmul (float r[4], const float q[4], const float p[4])
{
    // quaternion multiplication: r = q * p

    float w0 = q[3], w1 = p[3];
    float x0 = q[0], x1 = p[0];
    float y0 = q[1], y1 = p[1];
    float z0 = q[2], z1 = p[2];

    r[3] = w0 * w1 - x0 * x1 - y0 * y1 - z0 * z1;
    r[0] = w0 * x1 + x0 * w1 + y0 * z1 - z0 * y1;
    r[1] = w0 * y1 + y0 * w1 + z0 * x1 - x0 * z1;
    r[2] = w0 * z1 + z0 * w1 + x0 * y1 - y0 * x1;
}
```

Finally, rotating a 3D 'vector' `v` (or if you prefer, the 'point' `v` that the question has named `v1`, represented as a vector), using the quaternion: `float q[4]` has a somewhat strange formula: `v' = q * v * conjugate(q)`. Quaternions have conjugates, similar to complex numbers. Here's the routine:

```
static inline void
qrot (float v[3], const float q[4])
{
    // 3D vector rotation: v = q * v * conj(q)

    float r[4], p[4];

    r[0] = + v[0], r[1] = + v[1], r[2] = + v[2], r[3] = +0.0;
    glView__qmul(r, q, r);

    p[0] = - q[0], p[1] = - q[1], p[2] = - q[2], p[3] = q[3];
    glView__qmul(r, r, p);

    v[0] = r[0], v[1] = r[1], v[2] = r[2];
}
```

---

Putting it all together. Obviously you can make use of the `static` keyword where appropriate. Modern optimising compilers may ignore the `inline` hint depending on their own code generation heuristics. But let's just concentrate on correctness for now:

> How do I rotate a vector v1 about another vector v2 by an angle A?

Assuming some sort of `Vector3` class, and `(A)` in radians, we want the quaternion representing the rotation by the angle `(A)` about the axis `v2`, and we want to apply that quaternion rotation to `v1` for the result:

```
float q[4]; // we want to find the unit quaternion for `v2` and `A`...

make_quat(q, v2, A);

// what about `v1`? can we access elements with `operator [] (int)` (?)
// if so, let's assume the memory: `v1[0] .. v1[2]` is contiguous.
// you can figure out how you want to store and manage your Vector3 class.

qrot(& v1[0], q);

// `v1` has been rotated by `(A)` radians about the direction vector `v2` ...
```

---

Is this the sort of thing that folks would like to see expanded upon in the Beta Documentation site? I'm not altogether clear on its requirements, expected rigour, etc.

Comment: +1:  I personally think this is the best approach for a variety of reasons.  Shame you didn't answer sooner, you might have been the chosen answer.

Answer (score 6):

This may prove useful:

```
double c = cos(A);
double s = sin(A);
double C = 1.0 - c;

double Q[3][3];
Q[0][0] = v2[0] * v2[0] * C + c;
Q[0][1] = v2[1] * v2[0] * C + v2[2] * s;
Q[0][2] = v2[2] * v2[0] * C - v2[1] * s;

Q[1][0] = v2[1] * v2[0] * C - v2[2] * s;
Q[1][1] = v2[1] * v2[1] * C + c;
Q[1][2] = v2[2] * v2[1] * C + v2[0] * s;

Q[2][0] = v2[0] * v2[2] * C + v2[1] * s;
Q[2][1] = v2[2] * v2[1] * C - v2[0] * s;
Q[2][2] = v2[2] * v2[2] * C + c;

v1[0] = v1[0] * Q[0][0] + v1[0] * Q[0][1] + v1[0] * Q[0][2];
v1[1] = v1[1] * Q[1][0] + v1[1] * Q[1][1] + v1[1] * Q[1][2];
v1[2] = v1[2] * Q[2][0] + v1[2] * Q[2][1] + v1[2] * Q[2][2];
```

Comment: I don't know that's wrong here, but this one yields incorrect result

Comment: This answer was adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711058/868546

Answer (score 4):

Use a [3D rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

Answer (score 3):

I found this here:
http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/math/rotvec.html

```
let
    [v] = [vx, vy, vz]      the vector to be rotated.
    [l] = [lx, ly, lz]      the vector about rotation
          | 1  0  0|
    [i] = | 0  1  0|           the identity matrix        
          | 0  0  1|

          |   0  lz -ly |
    [L] = | -lz   0  lx |
          |  ly -lx   0 |

    d = sqrt(lx*lx + ly*ly + lz*lz)
    a                       the angle of rotation

then
```

matrix operations gives:

```
[v] = [v]x{[i] + sin(a)/d*[L] + ((1 - cos(a))/(d*d)*([L]x[L]))}
```

I wrote my own Matrix3 class and Vector3Library that implemented this vector rotation. It works absolutely perfectly. I use it to avoid drawing models outside the field of view of the camera.

I suppose this is the "use a 3d rotation matrix" approach. I took a quick look at quaternions, but have never used them, so stuck to something I could wrap my head around.