# Rotation of a point about the z-axis

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, 3d, rotation

I have 3 vectors in 3D space. Let's call them `xaxis`, `yaxis`, and `zaxis`. These vectors are centered about an arbitrary `point` somewhere in 3D space. I am interested in rotating the `xaxis` and `yaxis` vectors about the `zaxis` vector a number of degrees `θ`.

For the following code with values being arbitrary and unimportant:

```
double xaxis[3], yaxis[3], zaxis[3], point[3], theta;
```

How would I go about rotating `xaxis` and `yaxis` about the `zaxis` by `theta` degrees?

**Future Note: These attempts do not work. See my answer for the proper solution, which was found with the help of BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft**

My attempt at matrix-based rotation:

```
double rx[3][3];
double ry[3][3];
double rz[3][3];
double r[3][3];

rx[0][0] = 1;
rx[0][1] = 0;
rx[0][2] = 0;

rx[1][0] = 0;
rx[1][1] = cos(theta);
rx[1][2] = sin(theta);

rx[2][0] = 0;
rx[2][1] = -1.0 * sin(theta);
rx[2][2] = cos(theta);

ry[0][0] = cos(theta);
ry[0][1] = 0;
ry[0][2] = -1.0 * sin(theta);

ry[1][0] = 0;
ry[1][1] = 1;
ry[1][2] = 0;

ry[2][0] = sin(theta);
ry[2][1] = 0;
ry[2][2] = cos(theta);
//No rotation wanted on the zaxis
rz[0][0] = cos(0);
rz[0][1] = sin(0);
rz[0][2] = 0;

rz[1][0] = -1.0 * sin(0);
rz[1][1] = cos(0);
rz[1][2] = 0;

rz[2][0] = 0;
rz[2][1] = 0;
rz[2][2] = 1;

vtkMath::Multiply3x3(rx, ry, r); //Multiplies rx by ry and stores into r
vtkMath::Multiply3x3(r, rz, r); //Multiplies r by rz and stores into r

vtkMath::Multiply3x3(r, xaxis, xaxis);//multiplies a 3x3 by a 3x1
vtkMath::Multiply3x3(r, yaxis, yaxis);//multiplies a 3x3 by a 3x1
```

This attempt only worked when the plane was in the x-y plane:

```
double x, y;
x = xaxis[0];
y = xaxis[1];
xaxis[0] = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
xaxis[1] = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);

x = yaxis[0];
y = yaxis[1];
yaxis[0] = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
yaxis[1] = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
```

Using the axis-angle approach given by BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft:

```
double c = cos(theta);
double s = sin(theta);
double C = 1.0 - c;

double Q[3][3];
Q[0][0] = xaxis[0] * xaxis[0] * C + c;
Q[0][1] = xaxis[1] * xaxis[0] * C + xaxis[2] * s;
Q[0][2] = xaxis[2] * xaxis[0] * C - xaxis[1] * s;

Q[1][0] = xaxis[1] * xaxis[0] * C - xaxis[2] * s;
Q[1][1] = xaxis[1] * xaxis[1] * C + c;
Q[1][2] = xaxis[2] * xaxis[1] * C + xaxis[0] * s;

Q[2][0] = xaxis[1] * xaxis[2] * C + xaxis[1] * s;
Q[2][1] = xaxis[2] * xaxis[1] * C - xaxis[0] * s;
Q[2][2] = xaxis[2] * xaxis[2] * C + c;

double x = Q[2][1] - Q[1][2], y = Q[0][2] - Q[2][0], z = Q[1][0] - Q[0][1];
double r = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

//xaxis[0] /= r;
//xaxis[1] /= r;
//xaxis[2] /= r;

xaxis[0] = x;// ?
xaxis[1] = y;
xaxis[2] = z;
```

Comment: If you're programming in 3D, use a library and matrices. If not, this belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @chris This is programming, and I've attempted to use matrices with my limited knowledge of linear algebra, to no avail. I also do not have access to external libraries except VTK.

Comment: Well, with the matrix actually implemented to do rotation, the programming part is easy. I'd still say it has a more math focus on it in order to get the concept down. If you're doing more of this stuff you might want to pick up a book on the mathematics behind 3D programming. I read a pretty good one once, but I can't remember where I found it.

Comment: My advice would be to find the rotation algorithm first. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions), for instance, might be of help.

Comment: What you essentially need, mathematically, is [the mapping S₂ ✕ S₁ -> SO(3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO%283%29#Axis_of_rotation). (It's not given in that article, for details follow the links there, search elsewhere or ask on Math.SE)

Comment: `This attempt only worked when the plane was in the x-y plane` - If you are rotating about the z-axis, then you *are* rotating on the x-y plane.  I'm not sure what you're trying to get at here, but that should work; and if you insist on using a matrix, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Note: `zaxis` != z-axis.

Comment: i don't understand.  the x, y and z axes are the things you measure your 3 coordinates against.  you seem to be calling arbitrary vectors "xaxis" etc.  why?  your whole problem description sounds like you are trying to sound "correct" without actually thinking about what you are doing and what things mean.  if you could clarify what you actually want then i suspect the solution would be pretty easy, but at the moment it's just a confused mess.

Comment: @andrewcooke I have a plane defined by the three vectors, with `zaxis` as the normal to that plane. In a sense, I've generated my own coordinate system relative to the vectors centered about the `point`.

Comment: @Drise: So ultimately your problem is that you want to rotate a vector about another vector by a certain angle.  This is called the axis-angle representation of the rotation, and there is a simple way to convert it to a matrix-rotation using a skew-symmetric matrix.  For some reason they don't mention it in the skew-symmetric matrix article on wikipedia, but they *do* have it under the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle) article.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I think that sounds like a solution, however, it is above my understanding in the form it's presented in. Could you give a coded example?

Comment: @Drise: You don't even need to read the article, just look at the equations.  When they say `xxC+c`, they are just writing `x*x*C + c` more compactly *(`x` is the x-component of the axis, `C` and `c` are defined a few lines above that equation)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The compact versions of the equations were difficult to understand, but that clears it up. Thank you.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Check my implementation above, and correct me if I am off. It seems only to shrink / expand my axes.

Comment: @Drise:  You should use a `struct` instead of an array, so you can write `xaxis.x` rather than `xaxis[0]`.  Also, I think you meant to use `zaxis` everywhere you wrote `xaxis`.  The setup for Q looks correct *(though usually when dealing with matricies, we put the row number first, then the column number, not the other way around)*, but everything below that is not needed - the bottom-half of that section on wikipedia is describing how to go from rotation matrix --> axis-angle, which is irrelevant to you.  What you're missing is multiplying the rotation matrix by the vector you want to rotate.

Comment: Also you mistakenly wrote `xaxis[1]` instead of `xaxis[0]` for `Q[2][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft:

```
double c = cos(theta);
double s = sin(theta);
double C = 1.0 - c;

double Q[3][3];
Q[0][0] = zaxis[0] * zaxis[0] * C + c;
Q[0][1] = zaxis[1] * zaxis[0] * C + zaxis[2] * s;
Q[0][2] = zaxis[2] * zaxis[0] * C - zaxis[1] * s;

Q[1][0] = zaxis[1] * zaxis[0] * C - zaxis[2] * s;
Q[1][1] = zaxis[1] * zaxis[1] * C + c;
Q[1][2] = zaxis[2] * zaxis[1] * C + zaxis[0] * s;

Q[2][0] = zaxis[0] * zaxis[2] * C + zaxis[1] * s;
Q[2][1] = zaxis[2] * zaxis[1] * C - zaxis[0] * s;
Q[2][2] = zaxis[2] * zaxis[2] * C + c;

xaxis[0] = xaxis[0] * Q[0][0] + xaxis[0] * Q[0][1] + xaxis[0] * Q[0][2];
xaxis[1] = xaxis[1] * Q[1][0] + xaxis[1] * Q[1][1] + xaxis[1] * Q[1][2];
xaxis[2] = xaxis[2] * Q[2][0] + xaxis[2] * Q[2][1] + xaxis[2] * Q[2][2]; // Multiply a 3x3 by 3x1 and store it as the new rotated axis

yaxis[0] = yaxis[0] * Q[0][0] + yaxis[0] * Q[0][1] + yaxis[0] * Q[0][2];
yaxis[1] = yaxis[1] * Q[1][0] + yaxis[1] * Q[1][1] + yaxis[1] * Q[1][2];
yaxis[2] = yaxis[2] * Q[2][0] + yaxis[2] * Q[2][1] + yaxis[2] * Q[2][2]; // Multiply a 3x3 by 3x1 and store it as the new rotated axis
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that following matrix multiplication is wrong!

As stated above it can be factored with `xaxis[0]`

```
xaxis[0] = xaxis[0] * Q[0][0] + xaxis[0] * Q[0][1] + xaxis[0] * Q[0][2];

xaxis[0] = xaxis[0] * (Q[0][0] + Q[0][1] + Q[0][2]);
```

This does not look like a matrix multiplication. It should be:

```
xaxis1[0] = xaxis[0] * Q[0][0] + xaxis[1] * Q[0][1] + xaxis[2] * Q[0][2];
xaxis1[1] = xaxis[0] * Q[1][0] + xaxis[1] * Q[1][1] + xaxis[2] * Q[1][2];
xaxis1[2] = xaxis[0] * Q[2][0] + xaxis[1] * Q[2][1] + xaxis[2] * Q[2][2]; // Multiply a 3x3 by 3x1 and store it as the new rotated axis

yaxis1[0] = yaxis[0] * Q[0][0] + yaxis[1] * Q[0][1] + yaxis[2] * Q[0][2];
yaxis1[1] = yaxis[0] * Q[1][0] + yaxis[1] * Q[1][1] + yaxis[2] * Q[1][2];
yaxis1[2] = yaxis[0] * Q[2][0] + yaxis[1] * Q[2][1] + yaxis[2] * Q[2][2]; // Multiply a 3x3 by 3x1 and store it as the new rotated axis
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here. It's been quite some time since I've used this code, but it did in fact work when I last used it.